# TypeScript+SystemJS using JSON and Text plugins

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, typescript1.5, systemjs

Using *TypeScript* with *SystemJS*, how can I import a *JSON* file using `plugin-json`?

If I write `System.import('myjson.json!json').then(...)` then it imports it asynchronously and not as a part of `System.register([...])`.

So, how can I import a JSON file as a part of `System.register([...])` and convincing *TypeScript* to agree to this? (without `then` *Promise* syntax).

**Note:**
I'm using the `tsc` flag `-m system`

---

### Update:

A possible solution is to use the `-m umd` option for `tsc` instead of `-m system`, then I can do the following:

```
/// <reference path="typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
var myJson = require('myJson.json!json')
```

However, still waiting for an answer regarding usage of `-m system`.

Comment: Why not to download a json file via a http request? Module systems are not designed for such tasks.

Comment: @MaxFX I want to use the `plugin-json` SystemJS module so when I build everything, systemjs will embed it all to one JS file, same goes for HTML templates, when I import them (to be used as angular controller templates), I want them all to be embedded in the built minified JS file.

Loading via ajax will require putting these files too on production deployments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do : `import json = require('myJson.json!json')` You need to have some `.d.ts` file with the following:

```
declare module 'myJson.json!json'{
   var json:any;
   export = json;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using 'Ambient External Modules' works as expected, however, the down side is that I have to declare each JSON or TEXT import I'm gonna use, as opposed to when using `-m umd` like in the example I wrote above. do you mind pointing out the downside of using `umd`? (Still using SystemJS in the actual webapp).

Comment: None really. If `var/require` is what you want its okay.