# How to import .html fragment using es6 syntax in TypeScript

Tags: import, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to import an HTML template from a relative path like this:

```
import customSelectHtml from "./custom-select.html!text";
```

TypeScript compiler complains that it cannot find module. I was trying to create an ambient module definition, but it doesn't allow relative paths in module names. I am using SystemJS as a module loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible.

Due to the definition of what is [module](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#113-modules) in typescript, and as far as I know in ES6 javascript ([import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import)). Module cannot be html. The common approach is to import a javascript module that exports a string containing html, css, whatever. But that is not importing of the file with raw html.

Maybe you want to have a look at [html imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) also, but that is completely different thing.

Comment: Yep, imports is a completely different and unsupported thing. And workarounds are ugly. While it's actually possible with non-relative paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962590/typescriptsystemjs-using-json-and-text-plugins

Comment: It more a hack than actual way of doing it. Using approach I referred it 'fools' typescript into thinking of html as valid javascript. So far I would recommend to go with 'traditional' ways of dynamically loading content of files. But in any case - thanks for the link, it is useful.

Comment: Yes, after a bit of thinking I agree and consider using import syntax for loading html fragments a mistake and traditional loading is the right way.

Comment: So much for "typescript is a superset of javascript" >_<

Answer (score 5):

I'm not using typescript, but I do use ES6. Might be useful for you.

The way that I solve this is by declaring template strings using ` ` quotes. It works fine for me, I would be happy to know if someone thinks this is a bad habbit.

below a snippet with Angular(-ui-router).

index.js

```
var indexTemplate = `
<div>
    <h1>{{ Index page }}</h1>
</div
`

export {indexTemplate}
```

config.js

```
import { indexTemplate } from './index.js'

function config($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'indexController',
        template: indexTemplate
    })
}
```

For completeness, this assumes indexController is defined elsewhere. Also, this config function is exported to a place where app is defined. But that all is not related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SystemJS, but this is definitely possible with Webpack and the [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader)

Answer (score 1):

You can import it using require syntax

1) Create app.d.ts file and require definition so typescript know this is function. (you don;t need to add any addition library, systemJs support require syntax)

```
declare function require(params:string): any;
```

2) Now you can import your html using
var template = require('./custom-select.html!text')

I found it even better because you can use **require** inline

```
var directive = {
   template: require('./custom-select.html!text'),
   scope: {}
}
```

Comment: I know, but this it not an ES6 syntax and more verbose.

Comment: Does this need systemJs/Webpack or works with typescript compiler itself?

Comment: This needs SystemJs Text plugin

Comment: The important part is declaring a definition for "require" function. This makes Typescript ignore "require" function assuming its global n leave it alone. Then you can use appropriate webpack/systemjs plugins to load text,css, images, etc.