# I want to render a html file in my react Typescript project. How would I go about doing that?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Right now what I have tried is using dangerouslyinnerHTML to try getting this done but for some reason it only renders some of my html. How would I be able to completely call a HTML file in my typescript file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816192/how-to-import-external-html-files-into-a-typescript-class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36649795/102937

Comment: https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/importing-html-files-from-typescript-bd1c50909992